# How to get more precision in mouse movement

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, mouse

os:: windows xp sp3
Qt:: 4.6

I am playing with some 3D stuff and need to implement mouse moving. I tried with Qt mouseMoveEvent but found that is not good because mouseMoveEvent does not handle with every pixel when mouse is moved. I need somethig that register EVERY pixel of movement.
Searching for solution I cheked Qt online documentation && found QCursor class && its member pos().

Questions:: ***Does QCursor::pos() register every pixel in movement?*** Have somebody better idea for precise handling of camera wiew in 3d (i am not using openGL , building my engine in painter(it is for fun && hoby)  ) ?

Answer (score 2):

No, mouse may move several pixels at once. 
If you need the midway points for something then calculate them. Calculate all points on line between two positions of mouse. It is still unclear to me why you need the points, but that should help.

Comment: I need precise mouseMoving for 3D fps game i am building. So mouse must be sensitive on every pixel move because for now implementation is through mouseMoveEvent and is not smooth. Movement on that way is twitching. Need some smooth aprouch. Have you any idea or link how to achieve smoothnes.

Comment: May be [www.unp.me/f140/smooth-out-your-mouse-movement-38370/]?

Answer (score 2):

This most likely does not have much to do with Qt, but with your mouse polling rate. You might want to refer to this quite informative blog post on [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/mouse-dpi-and-usb-polling-rate.html).

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I had similar issue (I didn't use QT). Your system does not have that precise information.

What I did, was computing mouse position change (dx, dy) and using that information to move the camera. In many frameworks you don't have to compute (dx,dy) as you get that information with the event (for example SDL).

Alternatively you could compute position change and then interpolate positions between current and previous mouse position - then you could use those positions to move your camera.

You would have the same problem if you wanted to draw mouse movement on the screen. You can then use Bresenham's algorithm [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to generate pixels between two given points

Answer (score 0):

No, QCursor does not prvide that information, as it has no signal giving you this. You have to explicitly query its position and doing that in the mouseMoveEvent limits the precision again. The underlying window system just does not deliver that precision. Like the others said, just work with arbitrary wide movements or compute the intermediary points yourself.